# Не устанавливается cbrf_rates

Tags: python

```
pip install cbrf_rates

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cbrf_rates (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cbrf_rates
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Это пакет [8-летней давности](https://github.com/moskrc/cbrf-rates). И там всё содержание [десяток строк](https://github.com/moskrc/cbrf-rates/blob/master/cbrf_rates.py). Проще с того же `url` что в этом пакете данные через `Pandas` забрать, будет вообще две строчки:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp', encoding='cp1251')
```

В `df` тогда будет:

| index | ID | NumCode | CharCode | Nominal | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | R01010 | 36 | AUD | 1 | Австралийский доллар | 49,0935 |
| 1 | R01020A | 944 | AZN | 1 | Азербайджанский манат | 40,6625 |
| 2 | R01035 | 826 | GBP | 1 | Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства | 85,4263 |
| 3 | R01060 | 51 | AMD | 100 | Армянских драмов | 17,4716 |
| 4 | R01090B | 933 | BYN | 1 | Белорусский рубль | 26,1892 |
| 5 | R01100 | 975 | BGN | 1 | Болгарский лев | 38,4462 |
| 6 | R01115 | 986 | BRL | 1 | Бразильский реал | 13,5438 |
| 7 | R01135 | 348 | HUF | 100 | Венгерских форинтов | 19,3821 |
| 8 | R01150 | 704 | VND | 10000 | Вьетнамских донгов | 29,2846 |
| 9 | R01200 | 344 | HKD | 10 | Гонконгских долларов | 88,4534 |
| 10 | R01210 | 981 | GEL | 1 | Грузинский лари | 26,0943 |
| 11 | R01215 | 208 | DKK | 1 | Датская крона | 10,1096 |
| 12 | R01230 | 784 | AED | 1 | Дирхам ОАЭ | 18,8201 |
| 13 | R01235 | 840 | USD | 1 | Доллар США | 69,1263 |
| 14 | R01239 | 978 | EUR | 1 | Евро | 75,3348 |
| 15 | R01240 | 818 | EGP | 10 | Египетских фунтов | 23,1377 |
| 16 | R01270 | 356 | INR | 100 | Индийских рупий | 84,9659 |
| 17 | R01280 | 360 | IDR | 10000 | Индонезийских рупий | 46,2136 |
| 18 | R01335 | 398 | KZT | 100 | Казахстанских тенге | 14,9815 |
| 19 | R01350 | 124 | CAD | 1 | Канадский доллар | 51,6138 |
| 20 | R01355 | 634 | QAR | 1 | Катарский риал | 18,9907 |
| 21 | R01370 | 417 | KGS | 100 | Киргизских сомов | 80,2651 |
| 22 | R01375 | 156 | CNY | 1 | Китайский юань | 10,2491 |
| 23 | R01500 | 498 | MDL | 10 | Молдавских леев | 36,6448 |
| 24 | R01530 | 554 | NZD | 1 | Новозеландский доллар | 44,7938 |
| 25 | R01535 | 578 | NOK | 10 | Норвежских крон | 69,8987 |
| 26 | R01565 | 985 | PLN | 1 | Польский злотый | 15,9527 |
| 27 | R01585F | 946 | RON | 1 | Румынский лей | 15,4289 |
| 28 | R01589 | 960 | XDR | 1 | СДР (специальные права заимствования) | 93,2998 |
| 29 | R01625 | 702 | SGD | 1 | Сингапурский доллар | 52,6877 |
| 30 | R01670 | 972 | TJS | 10 | Таджикских сомони | 67,2415 |
| 31 | R01675 | 764 | THB | 10 | Таиландских батов | 21,1564 |
| 32 | R01700J | 949 | TRY | 10 | Турецких лир | 36,7656 |
| 33 | R01710A | 934 | TMT | 1 | Новый туркменский манат | 19,7504 |
| 34 | R01717 | 860 | UZS | 10000 | Узбекских сумов | 61,2133 |
| 35 | R01720 | 980 | UAH | 10 | Украинских гривен | 18,7173 |
| 36 | R01760 | 203 | CZK | 10 | Чешских крон | 31,5818 |
| 37 | R01770 | 752 | SEK | 10 | Шведских крон | 67,7709 |
| 38 | R01775 | 756 | CHF | 1 | Швейцарский франк | 75,1700 |
| 39 | R01805F | 941 | RSD | 100 | Сербских динаров | 64,3171 |
| 40 | R01810 | 710 | ZAR | 10 | Южноафриканских рэндов | 40,4917 |
| 41 | R01815 | 410 | KRW | 1000 | Вон Республики Корея | 56,1683 |
| 42 | R01820 | 392 | JPY | 100 | Японских иен | 53,5075 |

Там в пакете ещё правда дата парсилась из `XML`. Ну можете прочитать этот `XML` именно как `XML` и взять из него ещё дату, если нужно будет. `Pandas` всё кроме табличных данных игнорирует.